# Are rhetorical questions in comments discouraged?

Tags: discussion

So, someone posted some code with no context and said barely more than "it doesn't work, please help me".

I left a comment that looked something like this:

> Here's a schematic of an engine. It doesn't work. Can you fix it?

Now the comment is "disappeared" without a trace.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Somebody probably flagged it as rude. I'd ignore it, downvote the question, closevote if appropriate, walk away

Comment: Why would they be?

Comment: besides downvote and close, if possible, I hope you can help to improve the question, if the question cannot be edited to improve, at least describe why the question should close and then suggest some improvements

Comment: Your snark detector doesn't work.  Take it to a mechanic.

Answer (score 3):

Such comments don't help anyone. Your comment was probably flagged as "not constructive" or "rude" and then removed.

If the question is missing information, vote to close it.

Comment: I'd argue that, in thinking about such an allegory, there is help in the message.

Comment: @spender Worst case, you and OP get in an ugly argument. If you really want to comment, do it in a *nice* way. "Your question is missing some information about X and Y, can you add this information?" or something like that.

Comment: I guess the problem is not because it is a rhetorical question, but someone thinks it is rude, a comment can be help but rude at the same time

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the comment is rude. However, it is arguably not constructive.

After reading comment, a good deal of people will just stumble over the fact that *they* are not familiar with engines and won't further reflect on the problem of the absence of diagnosis information. If the very *concrete and immediate* issue of getting an answer to their question did not prompt them to include diagnosis information, why should an abstract and hypothetical scenario make them do so?

Also, some users just do not know *what* information they need to add to their question. Putting a comment that amounts to "your question lacks information" is not particularly useful for these users.

It is preferable to be straightforward: "Please edit your question to add A, B, C." Not only does this help the OP get it, it also helps with getting closevoters to vote. When I consider that adding such a comment will largely be a waste of my time, I just downvote and vote to close without a comment.